# How to compile the Xamarin android app with C# classlibrary + C++ Native library?

Tags: android, android-ndk, xamarin.android, java-native-interface

I have a Chip card reader application which is written by C# and C++ lib as a low-level layer.

Now I want to have the same application in IOS and Android.

So for to achieve this, I have setup the XamarinSDK in VS2017.

I have created the sample android app and imported my existing card reader c# class library and I have calling C++ methods using DllImport inside the C# library and finally compiled both successfully without error.

But when I run the APK on the device it showing exception when calling C++ lib from C# lib.

The code flow is like below image.

[image]

So can anyone help me about how to achieve this same?

Highly appreciated your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Your libs must be compatible with the Android platform. If they're written to Windows or other platform you have to recompile and maybe adapt them. The C# lib tend to be an PCL or .Net Standard lib and the C++ lib have to target the android platform.

I don't have experience with C++ Android development but all C++ applications and libraries have to be compatible with the platform they run.